# How to display specific elements on a page at a specific screen resolution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adaptive-layout

How to display specific elements on a page at a specific screen resolution. A kind of mobile version for the site, something like media queries, only which will display a certain block of js (react) / html (jsx) code at a certain resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [answer on this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237935/jquery-execute-scripts-based-on-screen-size)

If you're using `JSX` the usage should be wrapped into `{}` for example:

```js
render() {
    return (
        // ...
        // In my knowledge JS event listeners are more taxing on the performance
        {
            if($(window).width() >= 1024){
                return <div className="bigger-than-1024"> RENDERED CONDITIONALLY </div>
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The better way to do this might be to still render it and then use CSS classes and media queries to not display it:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
    .bigger-than-1024 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: My JS example might not be the best as it depends on a re-render vs. adding a listener in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method